# Calculate average instead of counting in barchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, charts, dc.js

I have dc.js bar-chart,
the y axis for the chart is counting the number each element in the x axis(level)
but I don't want to count the number of each level
I want to calculate the average of the GPA.

The problem is that the char is dealing with one column only
but want two columns

This the data in the csv(mep,csv):

```
GPA,level,gender,year
3.34,B+,F,2003
1.98,C-,M,2003
2.81,B-,M,2005
2.12,C,M,2006
```

This the call of Java script function:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    d3.csv("mep.csv", function(d) {return d;}
      ,function(error, rows) {
      grid ("#ep2014list",rows);
      });      
    });      
</script>
```

This the bar-chart code:

```
<script>
function grid (selector,data) {
  var ndx = crossfilter(data),
      all = ndx.groupAll();
  var bar_level = dc.barChart(selector + " .level");
  var level = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
      if (typeof d.level == "undefined") return "";
      return d.level;
      });
  var levelGroup   = level.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return 1; });
  bar_level
    .width(700)
    .height(200)
    .outerPadding(0)
    .gap(1)
    .margins({top: 10, right: 0, bottom: 100, left: 30})
    .x(d3.scale.ordinal())
    .xUnits(dc.units.ordinal)
    .brushOn(false)
    .elasticY(true)
    .yAxisLabel("#Avg")
    .dimension(level)
    .group(levelGroup); 
dc.renderAll();
}
</script>
<div id="ep2014list">
</br></br></br></br>
<div class="group"></div>
<div class="dc-data-count">
</div>
</div>
<div id="ep2014list">
<div class="level"></div>
<div class="dc-data-count">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What  do you mean by "the char is dealing with one column only but want two columns"?

Comment: The [annotated stock example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/stock.html) shows how to do an average. But you probably mean something else..